# Google map api usage for localhost

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hi i have generated the client key for google map, now i am using in my application i am getting the below error, Can anyone help me how to use for localhost.

```
Google Maps API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#referer-not-allowed-map-error
Your site URL to be authorized: http://localhost:8085/ParticiPoint/#/createLocation
```

I have authorized the my localhost address in **Accept requests from these HTTP referrers (websites) column**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you creating map api key just leave blank the site url input. It says "If you leave it blank your map request will work anywhere" or sth. like that

Comment: this is not a safe solution, use @Sudhir solution instead

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution by adding **http://localhost** in Accept requests from these HTTP referrers (websites) column